# Trying to copy HTML from one file to another using batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm manipulating some HTML via Batch but even though I've `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`, it still won't transfer tags. This is my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.html) do call :putLineInHTMLFile %%x
:putLineInHTMLFile
echo !%*!>> output.html
```

file.html contains:

```
<tag 1>
<tag 2>
```

After running the script, output.html contains:

```
ECHO is off.
```

P.S.: I would like to keep using `do call` so I'm interested in an answer that makes this work without removing the `do call` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.html) do call :putLineInHTMLFile "%%x"
goto :EOF

:putLineInHTMLFile
set "line=%~1"
echo !line!>> output.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.html) do (echo %%x>> output.html)
```

Edit: Here's an alternative using `do call`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.html) do (set Blog="%%x"& call :DoIt)
goto :End
:DoIt
echo %Blog%>>output.html

:End
```

Re-edit: Fixed my 2nd following @Aacini answer. His answer made me realize that `%%x` needs to be surrounded with `"` instead of being assigned to another var uselessly.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.html) do (call :DoIt "%%x")
goto :End
:DoIt
echo %1>>output.html

:End
```

Comment: Can you alter your answer so that it uses `do call` ? :)

Comment: Added a `do call` alternative.

Comment: Actually, the second solution outputs the tags between quotes :). Aacini's answer works because of that extra set he has in there. If there's one thing I'd modify on this website is the ability to at least give as much points to a person that answers even if it's not the complete solution. Thank you for your time & effort! :)