# Can't escape semicolon inside quotes in batch file using enableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file

I'm manipulating some HTML via Batch. I'm using delayed expansion but when a semicolon is encountered inside double quotes, the script fails to copy anything after and including the semicolon.

It's probably due to the fact that I use double quotes when I pass the variable to the `putLineInHTMLFile` label (I **need** to keep things separated in labels).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.html) do call :putLineInHTMLFile "%%x"
goto :EOF
:putLineInHTMLFile
set "line=%~1"
echo !line!>> output.html
```

file.html contains:

```
<tag1>
<tag"bla;2">
```

After running the script, output.html contains:

```
<tag1>
<tag"bla
```

I've tried escaping the semicolon with ^ or ^^. Didn't work. I've tried escaping the double quotes too. That didn't work either.

I can change the contents of `file.html` anyway I please just as long as I can include that semicolon in the output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for the test-case given; no guarantees for wider use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=# tokens=*" %%x in (file.html) do (
        set "safe=%%x"
        set "safe=!safe:"=""!"
        call :putLineInHTMLFile "!safe!"
)
goto :eof
:putLineInHTMLFile
set "line=%~1"
set "line=%line:""="%"
echo !line!>> output.html
:eof
```

Within the "body" of the `for` command, the `%%x` has not been split, it's only when processed by the `call` command that this happens. To protect that, I've used `safe` to double-up all double-quotes in the string, and then added a line in the subroutine to strip them out again.

This doesn't work properly if the double-quotes aren't matched, but in those cases, neither does the echoing of the trailing `>`, even when there are no semi-colons present.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. The problem is that the subroutine receives

> "<tag"bla;2">"

for that line. The parser sees that as

Token1 : "<tag"bla
Token2 : 2">"

because `;` like <kbd>Space</kbd> is a separator.

Sadly, without knowing what you intend to do within the subroutine, it's difficult to advise on how to circumvent the problem.

---

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43391363.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "outfile2=%destdir%\outfile2.txt"
del "%outfile%"
del "%outfile2%"

(for /f "delims=" %%x in (%filename1%) do set "line=%%x"&call :putLineInHTMLFile "%%x")>"%outfile2%"
goto :eof

:putLineInHTMLFile
ECHO %*
echo !line!>>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.
I used a file named `q43391363.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces files defined as %outfile% and %outfile2%

So - here's two different ways, one using conventional output direct to `outfile1` and the other using redirection from a subroutine into `outfile2`.

Comment: I'm building a HTML file from multiple other sources, including two other HTML files containing footer & header. Is there any way I can escape the semicolon? I can alter the footer & header "HTML" files since they're not really HTML. They're text that I can manipulate as I wish.

Answer (score 1):

This method works in all cases, as long as the quotes be matched (even number) in the input lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
del output.html
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.html) do call :putLineInHTMLFile "%%x"
goto :EOF

:putLineInHTMLFile
set line=%*
echo !line:~1,-1!>> output.html
```

PS - Please, do not include additional parts that not appears in the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373088/trying-to-copy-html-from-one-file-to-another-using-batch/43375175#43375175), like the `:eof` label... The label is written in uppercase letters in `goto :EOF` command to indicate that it is special. Type `goto /?` for further details.

Comment: Got it. I edited my original post. Thank you for your help in all this :).